# SMS verification code is sent only for JIO carrier

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The firebase phone Auth is unable to send the verification code for all the valid numbers, I have tried around 6 number out of which the verification code is sent only for 2 numbers, especially Vodafone number never received the OTP.

Initially, when I started the app the phone authentication was working fine but later as the number of test cases increased, phone auth just stopped to send the OTP, currently, the OTP is generated only for my JIO number.

Comment: You should contact the firebase support regarding this. This is not a programming related question, so it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#phone_number_sign-in_limits) Firebase Phone number sign-in limits, this problem cannot occur.

However, you should use Test Number Firebase in the case of Debug to avoid these errors.

Also, I had this problem with me before and contacted the Firebase support team, but the problem was not with them, so I contacted the local network support team and the problem appeared to them.

I hope I helped you.